# ref.update() removes omitted keys - works just like .set()?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to use Firebase realtime database .update() to update a data node according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update). I am using .update() to selectively update only the referenced keys at the location - instead of replacing all the keys at the location.

My problem is that I have omitted key "createdAt" from the update object since I don't wish to update "createdAt" after initial create - but the "createdAt" key gets removed when using .update()! ｢(ﾟﾍﾟ)

**Database structure**

[image: Database structure]

**Object sent to update()**

```
{
  "data": {
    "notifyByEmail": false,
    "notifyByPush": false,
    "notifyBySms": false
  },
  "access/members": {
    "1234567890": true,
    "0987654321": true
  }
}
```

**Code**

```
console.log('api', `${myPath}/${id}`, dbUpdateObj)
database.ref(`${myPath}/${id}`).update(dbUpdateObj).then(() => {   
  resolve({id, reduxStoreObj})
})
```

**Logging**

```
api categories/-LqXvFkeF_QfA5oHquYp [+] Object { data: {…}, "access/members": {…} }
```

**Result**

[image: Result after .update()]

Why is "createdAt" removed? I thought .update() should only update defined keys and not touch omitted keys.

What have I missed?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `update` acts like separate calls to `set` to each of the properties you pass in. So in your case the `data` and `access/members` get completely replaced, but all other properties under `` database.ref(`${myPath}/${id}`) `` stay unmodified.

If you want to update deeper level properties, include their entire path in the update map. So to maintain `data/createdAt`, specify the entire path to the `notify...` properties that you want to update:

```
{
  "data/notifyByEmail": false,
  "data/notifyByPush": false,
  "data/notifyBySms": false,
  "access/members": {
    "1234567890": true,
    "0987654321": true
  }
}
```

---

I find that it's most common to have a flat map of complete paths in such multi-path update statements. So to also maintain the existing member of `access/members`, the above would become:

```
{
  "data/notifyByEmail": false,
  "data/notifyByPush": false,
  "data/notifyBySms": false,
  "access/members/1234567890": true,
  "access/members/0987654321": true
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank! As always - flat map is part of the solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.set()` with the `{merge: true}` option to avoid the (not changed) data be replaced by the new data.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Hi @tobias! Thank you for the reply. Isn't that exclusively for Cloud Firestore? I am using Realtime database.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't  get that, the merge option is only available for Firestore. If your'e just getting started with it, I'd recommend using Firestore instead of Firebase RTDB.

Comment: Thanks! I have evaluated both and already have a large project based on RTDB. :)